# Node.js Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, terminal

Hi I'm currently trying to solve an issue with node.js Im using node to read a txt file. When added on the commandline the name of the file it should list out all items within the txt file and it does. How ever when I'm trying to list one out from the command line, it lists the chosen line from the txt file but throws up an error.

```js
// Make sure we got a filename on the command line.
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
   console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME');
   process.exit(1);
}
// Read the file and print its contents. And split into an array after each space
var fs    = require('fs') , filename = process.argv[2];
var array = fs.readFileSync('dependencies.txt').toString().split('\n');
//console.log(array[0]);

if(process.argv[3]){
    var test = process.argv[3];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
       var pattern = /([^\s]+)/g;
       var line = pattern.exec(array[i]);
       if(test == line[0]){
          console.log(array[i]);
       }
    }
}


fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('OK: ' + filename);
   console.log(data)
});
```

[image: error]

Comment: I think you can get away with updating condition to `if(line && test == line[0]){`

Comment: perfect thanks been scratching my head at that for too long. Is there an easy way for it to accept more parameters?